# Create multiple instances of a class

Tags: python, class, pygame

I'm working on a space invaders type of game in Pygame. So far I just have the basics of the game down:

```
import pygame, sys, os, math, random, time
from pygame.locals import *

pygame.init()

window = pygame.display.set_mode((1000,500))
screen = pygame.display.get_surface()

spaceBackground = pygame.image.load("C:/Users/LN/Desktop/space-background.png")
spaceShip = pygame.image.load("C:/Users/LN/Desktop/space-ship.png")
bullet = pygame.image.load("C:/Users/LN/Desktop/bullet.png")
enemyShip = pygame.image.load("C:/Users/LN/Desktop/enemyAircraft.png")
class move():
    '''Move the space ship'''

    def _init_(self):
        screen.blit(spaceBackground, (0,0))
        self.position = spaceShip.get_rect()
        self.position = self.position.move(500,477)
        global place
        place = self.position
        pygame.display.flip()

    def moveUp(self):
        screen.blit(spaceBackground, self.position, self.position)
        self.position = self.position.move(0,-2)
        global place
        place = self.position

    def moveDown(self):
        screen.blit(spaceBackground, self.position, self.position)
        self.position = self.position.move(0,2)
        global place
        place = self.position

    def moveLeft(self):
        screen.blit(spaceBackground, self.position, self.position)
        self.position = self.position.move(-2,0)
        global place
        place = self.position

    def moveRight(self):
        screen.blit(spaceBackground, self.position, self.position)
        self.position = self.position.move(2,0)
        global place
        place = self.position

    def update(self):
        screen.blit(spaceShip, self.position)

    def notTooLow(self):
        if self.position[1] < (478):
            return True
        else:
            return False

    def notTooHigh(self):
        if self.position[1] > (4):
            return True
        else:
            return False
    def notTooRight(self):
        if self.position[0] < (974):
            return True
        else:
            return False

    def notTooLeft(self):
        if self.position[0] > (5):
            return True
        else:
            return False


class shoot():
    '''Shoots bullets out of the ship'''

    def _init_(self):
        global bulletUp
        bulletUp = False
        self.position = (0,0)

    def startMoveUp(self):
        self.position = place
        self.position = self.position.move(11,0)

    def bulletOnScreen(self):
        if self.position[1] > -5:
            return True
        else:
            global bulletUp
            bulletUp = False

    def moveUp(self):
        screen.blit(spaceBackground, self.position)
        self.position = self.position.move(0,-6)
        screen.blit(bullet, self.position)
        screen.blit(spaceShip, place)


class enemy():
    '''Spawn and control enemies'''

    def _init_(self):
        global numbEnemy
        numbEnemy = 0
        self.position = enemyShip.get_rect()

    def moveSpawn(self):
        self.position = self.position.move(0,50)

    def spawnEnemy(self):                                 
        screen.blit(enemyShip, (500, 20))
        self.position = enemyShip.get_rect()

    def moveEnemy(self):
        screen.blit(spaceBackground, self.position)
        self.position = self.position.move(0,1)
        screen.blit(enemyShip, self.position)






move = move()
move._init_()
shoot = shoot()
shoot._init_()
enemy = enemy()
enemy._init_()



counter = 0
while True:
    if counter//300*300 == counter:
        enemy.spawnEnemy()
    if counter//2*2 == counter:
        enemy.moveEnemy()
    if pygame.key.get_pressed()[K_UP] and move.notTooHigh():
        move.moveUp()
    pygame.event.pump()
    if pygame.key.get_pressed()[K_DOWN] and move.notTooLow():
        move.moveDown()
```

What I'm not sure how to do, is create multiple enemy ships. Is there a simple way to make it so I can spawn another ship, without deleting the other?

Comment: You need to create new `enemy` instance: `newEnemy = enemy(); newEnemy.spawnEnemy()`

Comment: I think you're misunderstanding what classes are. A class is a kind of thing. I don't see any way in which `move` or `shoot` could be kinds of things.

Comment: Also, `__init__` is supposed to have two underscores on each side. It's implicitly called when an instance of a class is created; you shouldn't have to explicitly call the `__init__` method after creating an object.

Comment: I think you should learn Python before you go jumping into making games...For using Pygame effectively you need at LEAST an adequate understanding of Object-Oriented Programming in Python, which you don't seem to have.

Comment: Ok.... I understand how classes work (except for the __init__ thing, that was useful), I just don't know how I can repeatably create new classes without manually making them. Is there a way to automatically make them in the code?

Comment: @user2749129 Of course there is a way, but I think you should reread the basics of OOP in Python before you try using the Pygame module. Game programming requires good knowledge of OOP techniques. Specifically read about how objects work in Python and how they get deleted (when references to them disappear). After you've learned that, you should go over the basic theory behind a good "game loop".

Comment: @Shashank Gupta Ok, that actually sounds like a good idea, do you happen to have a good link that could explain classes to me better? Btw, sorry I sounded kinda like a douche, I guess I don't understand how objects work...

Comment: @user2749129 I don't know any off the top of my head. But basically just Google around and I'm sure you'll find a lot of things. Also make sure you learn how a basic game loop works. :P I'd be happy to teach you here but you'd kinda have to ask another question (or several more).

Comment: @Shashank Gupta Thanks! Just real quickly, could explain how a good loop would be formatted, just so I know what to look for?

Comment: @user2749129 This is where I learned the basics of game loops: http://www.koonsolo.com/news/dewitters-gameloop/ Pygame has some additional things like an event queue and a clock tick function, but overall that link will tell you the basic theory behind it.

Comment: @ShashankGupta Actually, I have 1 more quick question. Is there a way to practice my OOP understanding? Before I go on I want to make sure I've learned it all.

Comment: @user2749129 If you've gone through the Python tutorial on classes and understand everything, that's basically all you need! Usually in games, each game object (like a ship, or an enemy) has its own `update` method and its own `draw` method. These methods are explained in the game loop article. To create multiple ships, you usually, store all of the ships inside a list so you can keep references to all of them. That way Python won't delete them (Python deletes any objects that it loses reference to).

Comment: @user2749129 In every iteration of the game loop, you go through all of your game objects and call their `update` method. Once you've done that you go through all the objects again and call their `draw` method. That's basically how OOP works in game programming.

Comment: @ShashankGupta Hmmm that was actually a really good way of explaining it! That makes sense. real quickly back to my original question though, how would I be able to generate an x amount of objects?

Comment: @user2749129 I'll put a generic example in an answer.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Let's say you have a class called enemy in your game. For the sake of brevity, I won't define the functions explicitly and will just use `pass` statements as placeholders.

```
class Enemy:
    def __init__(self):
        pass

    def update(self):
        pass

    def draw(self, display_surface):
        pass
```

To create multiple enemies you just need to do create a list of enemies where you will store all your reference to your currently active enemy objects.

```
enemies = []
```

To add a single enemy, you just append a call of the constructor of `enemy` to your list. You can do this as many times as you want.

```
enemies.append(Enemy())
```

As @monkey also mentioned in the comments, you can easily use list comprehension to set your list of active enemies to multiple object instances at once.

```
enemies = [Enemy() for x in range(10)]
```

Then in your game loop, you do something like the following in every iteration:

```
for enemy in enemies: # loop through all your active enemies
    enemy.update() # Update the state of every enemy.

for enemy in enemies: # once again loop through all your active enemies
    enemy.draw(display_surface) # Draw the image of every enemy to the display surface.
```

And that is a basic example of how you neatly do object-oriented game programming in Pygame.

Comment: Thanks a ton! I feel like I actually am beginning to get a basic understanding of OOP and how game loops work!

Comment: You can also use list comprehension: `enemies = [Enemy() for x in range(10)) ]`

Comment: @monkey Would doing that just create multiple Enemy() objects?

Comment: @Shashank Gupta Also, why create one update function and one draw function. Why not just combine the two to simplify it?

Comment: @Newbie404 because in a game loop you have an "update phase" and a "draw phase". You always want to update the state of *all* of your game objects separately before you start drawing anything. In a real game, this could be an instance of a Player class, several instances of Enemy classes, several instances of "Bullet" classes and so on. Furthermore in your draw phase of the game loop, you may want to draw certain objects on top of others. For example you may want to make it so that the player class always overlaps enemy classes (it's important to see the player!)....

Comment: @Newbie404 in that case, you would want to draw all of the enemies first and then draw the player. Having `draw` and `update` as separate methods just gives you a lot more control over the ordering behind things. And it lets you neatly separate the "draw" and "update" phases of your game loop. For more information on how basic  game loops work, I would suggest you check out this link: http://gamedev.tutsplus.com/articles/glossary/quick-tip-what-is-the-game-loop/